# How do I push additional branches to Stash?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

On my local machine, I have the following branches:

```
master
my-branch-one
my-branch-two
```

In Atlassian Stash, I have the following branches:

```
master
```

The `master` branch on my machine is up to date with the `master` branch in Stash.

How do I get the other two branches that are currently only on my local machine, onto Stash?

Notes:

1. These are branches actual local branches.

Answer (score 1):

If those are actual local branches (visible when you type `git branch` in the repo), then, following "[using branches in Stash](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+branches+in+Stash)", you should see those branches in the branches field:

[image: https://confluence.atlassian.com/download/attachments/374440753/Stash030-branch-listing.png?version=1&modificationDate=1400053671600&api=v2&effects=border-simple,blur-border]

If your stash displays a remote repo (not your local repo on your machine), then you would need to push those 2 branches on your remote repo first, before Stash is able to detect them.

```
git checkout my-branch-one
git push -u origin my-branch-one
```

Comment: yes, these are actual local branches. I have updated the question. In the "using stash" page that you linked to, it seems to just have instructions for creating new branches in stash, using the "correct" Stash conventions...

Comment: @power then Stash should  detect your existing localbranch for you? Just make sure your setting are set to Custom  (https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+branches+in+Stash#UsingbranchesinStash-model) for the branch model.